# Can we return a structure containing an array inside in C?

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

Here is a structure:

```
struct elem {
    int a[100];
    int val;
};

elem foo() {
    elem Result;
    Result.a[0] = 5;
    return Result;
}

int main () {
    elem aux = foo();
    //is Result passed back to aux, so that we can use its array?
    cout<<aux.a[0]<<"\n"; // 5
}
```

I know that functions ca return simple structures. 
Can they also return structures that contain arrays? What happens within the memory?

And also: when we declare   elem Result;   in the function, is the array initialised with 0, or it just takes random values?

Comment: Yes We Can!!!!!

Comment: If you _want_ it to be initialized to zero, `elem Result = {0};` is a very concise way to do so. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value/9812815

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, in both C and C++.

The array is copied element-by-element along with the rest of the struct. This might be slow for large arrays.

---

> is the array initialised with 0, or it just takes random values?

The array is not initialized, so it contains indeterminate values. Accessing them causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Why aren't the arrays returned in the same way (copied when returned)?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ probably because it's slow for large arrays and so the C standard wants to discourage it.

Comment: @AndreiMargeloiu; Because array have special feature that when they used in an expression they converted to pointer to its first element, with some exception. Arrays can't return from a function.

Comment: So, if we want a function to return an array, can we 'pack' the array in a struct ?

Comment: @AndreiMargeloiu Yes. Usually in C you declare the array outside the function and pass a pointer to the array into the function to fill it.

Comment: If an array is not initialised, accessing its elements gives undefined behaviour.   Containing "random values" is only one possible manifestation of that.